# ElasticSearch Delete By Query - delete multiple values

Tags: elasticsearch

Using the following ElasticSearch query to delete all documents with sourceId 1:

```
POST http://{{elasticip}}:9200/index2/index2_doc/_delete_by_query

{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "sourceId": 1
    }
  }
}
```

What is the proper syntax of the body if I wanted to delete from sourceId 1, 2, and 3 all at once?

Comment: You can use terms query with multiple Ids or multiple match query in should clause

Comment: {
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "filter" : {
        "terms" : {
          "sourceId" : [1,2,3]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: @Stpete111, you can try @LeBigCats;s answer

Comment: Hi @LeBigCat .  Thanks!  That syntax works.  Are you sure you don't want to post that as the answer so I can mark it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use bool terms filter:

```
{ "query" : { "bool" : { "filter" : { "terms" : { "sourceId" : [1,2,3] } } } } }
```

note: jaspreet advices are also corrects.